# How to delete corrupt local EKS Anywhere cluster

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl, kubernetes-cluster

I've created a local EKS Anywhere cluster following [this tutorial](https://anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/docs/getting-started/local-environment/).

```sh
$ CLUSTER_NAME=dev-cluster
$ eksctl anywhere generate clusterconfig $CLUSTER_NAME \
   --provider docker > $CLUSTER_NAME.yaml
$ eksctl anywhere create cluster -f $CLUSTER_NAME.yaml
```

After creating the cluster, I tried to delete it, but while it was still processing the deletion, I pressed Ctrl C to stop the operation, but it seems like the cluster is corrupt and I can no longer delete it.

```sh
$ eksctl anywhere delete cluster -f ${CONFIG_FILE}
Performing provider setup and validations
Creating management cluster
collecting cluster diagnostics
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x2479de7]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/aws/eks-anywhere/pkg/workflows.(*CollectDiagnosticsTask).Run(0x0, 0x2b04168, 0xc000130008, 0xc00015efd0, 0xc061b451d05e8958, 0xc000c83440)
        /codebuild/output/src572116999/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws.eks-anywhere/pkg/workflows/diagnostics.go:23 +0x67
github.com/aws/eks-anywhere/pkg/workflows.(*deleteManagementCluster).Run(0xc0004824f8, 0x2b04168, 0xc000130008, 0xc00015efd0, 0x13, 0x2)
        /codebuild/output/src572116999/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws.eks-anywhere/pkg/workflows/delete.go:172 +0x191
github.com/aws/eks-anywhere/pkg/task.(*taskRunner).RunTask(0xc000a93ba8, 0x2b04168, 0xc000130008, 0xc00015efd0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /codebuild/output/src572116999/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws.eks-anywhere/pkg/task/task.go:115 +0x1ef
github.com/aws/eks-anywhere/pkg/workflows.(*Delete).Run(0xc000a93c80, 0x2b04168, 0xc000130008, 0xc000a76330, 0xc0004d57a0, 0xc000c85300, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0007d1cc0)
        /codebuild/output/src572116999/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws.eks-anywhere/pkg/workflows/delete.go:53 +0x145
github.com/aws/eks-anywhere/cmd/eksctl-anywhere/cmd.(*deleteClusterOptions).deleteCluster(0x37fb100, 0x2b04168, 0xc000130008, 0xc00041cec0, 0x0)
        /codebuild/output/src572116999/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws.eks-anywhere/cmd/eksctl-anywhere/cmd/deletecluster.go:120 +0x389
github.com/aws/eks-anywhere/cmd/eksctl-anywhere/cmd.glob..func2(0x37cc180, 0xc00041cec0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
        /codebuild/output/src572116999/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws.eks-anywhere/cmd/eksctl-anywhere/cmd/deletecluster.go:36 +0xb3
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x37cc180, 0xc00041cea0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x37cc180, 0xc00041cea0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:852 +0x472
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x37cb280, 0x8, 0xc000000180, 0x2496ec5)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:960 +0x375
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:897
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteContext(...)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:890
github.com/aws/eks-anywhere/cmd/eksctl-anywhere/cmd.Execute(0x0, 0x0)
        /codebuild/output/src572116999/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws.eks-anywhere/cmd/eksctl-anywhere/cmd/root.go:43 +0x53
main.main()
        /codebuild/output/src572116999/src/git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/aws.eks-anywhere/cmd/eksctl-anywhere/main.go:29 +0xe5
```

The main error seems to be:

> invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

How can I manually delete this local cluster? `brew uninstall aws/tap/eks-anywhere` doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: I am on Mac. Perhaps just knowing the location the cluster was installed at, I can just `rm -rf` the directory. I am fine with completely uninstalling eks-anywhere

Comment: I'm looking at my docker UI, and I see lots of images. Is the cluster just running in a docker image?